# В чём разница между терминалом, консолью и оболочкой?

Tags: linux, консоль, unix, shell

Часто вижу термины *"терминал"*, *"виртуальный терминал"*, *"tty"*, *"консоль"*, *"командная оболочка"*. В чём отличие между ними? Или это синонимы? Даже на этом форуме для [терминал](/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb) предлагают синоним [консоль](/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c).

Comment: [отсюда](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB) и далее по ссылкам. [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB)

Comment: Вот [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/112797/) дается развернутый ответ на вопрос.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin@Alexey Vesker хотелось бы видеть каноничный ответ на этот достаточно популярный вопрос на ruSO.